# Website navigation bar without line wrap

Tags: html, css

(HTML / CSS newbie here) It seems I cannot find the right specifier to prevent a menu bar
from wrapping around to the next line if the user narrows the browser window under a certain threshold. My working sample is this:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float_advanced

Below is the unmodified code from that site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
} 

li {
float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 120px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I found some references to "white-space: nowrap;" but I couldn't get it to work (maybe because none of these other samples related to such a simple example as above). Any clues appreciated !

Best,
Chris

Comment: `white-space` won’t work here, since you are floating the LI. Either remove float and use `display:inline-block` instead, or – just give the UL a (min-)width. Since your links have a specific width set anyway, it should be easy enough to calculate the necessary overall width for the UL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add some css `width` to the `<ul>` with the fixed width of your navbar, like in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7cR29/)

or if the width of your navbar is fluid, use css `min-width` rather than `width`